# How to prove that $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive exactly when $a+b+c$, $ab+bc+ca$, $abc$ are positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

How could I prove that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive exactly when: 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rc}
a + b + c &>& 0 \\
ab + bc + ca &>& 0 \\ 
abc &>& 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I'm not sure if the definition of a Field could help me here.

Comment: w/o further constraints on the numbers, $a,b,c$ need not be positive. e.g. $a+b + c = ab+bc+ca = abc = 3$ has a pair of complex solutions. The statement do work if you assume $a,b,c$ are real.

Comment: @achillehui.  How would you order the complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are supposed to be real numbers

Comment: @ChristianMeyer consider the polynomial $P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = x^3 - (a+b+c)*x^2 + (ab+bc+ca)*x - abc$. Notice $P(x) < 0$ whenever $x \le 0$, so its real roots $a,b,c$ cannot be non-positive.

Comment: @WilliamElliot there is no need to order any complex number, the conditions can be interpreted as you are given 3 complex numbers $a,b,c$ if the three expression $a+b+c, ab+bc+ca, abc$ are real and positive, then can one conclude, $a,b,c$ are real and positive.

Comment: @achillehui . i was about to post an elementary algebraic proof but that is so much easier. You could copy it verbatim as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b<0$ and $c<0$.

Thus, since $abc>0$, we obtain $a>0$.

Hence,
$$bc>a(-b-c)>(-b-c)(-b-c)=(b+c)^2.$$
Id est,
$$b^2+bc+c^2<0.$$
Can you end it now?

Actually, since our field is ordered, we see that $2\neq0.$

Answer (score 0):

from $abc>0$ you can say-

1) $a>0$ and $b,c<0$ or

2)$a,b,c>0$ (done)

Case 1- $\implies bc>0$ so $a>b+c$ (from 1st condition)

and 2nd condition yields $ab+bc+ac>0$ $$\implies bc-a(b+c)>0\implies bc-(b+c)^2>0\implies -b^2-c^2-bc>0$$ which is a contradiciton as they are clearly $<0$ for nonzero a,b and c.